# "scale_color_gradient" in ggplot Python is not working?

Tags: python, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization, python-ggplot

Every time I try this it does not work the normal plot is what I see 
I tried to search about it but there is no problem like mine

```
gg = ggplot(d,aes('x', 'y',color = 'x')) + geom_point() + 
     scale_color_gradient(low='red', high='white')
```

I want to show saturation of color in my data between white and red.
I even tried to set no parameters in `scale_color_gradient()` but it doesn't work.

I checked this http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/scale_color_gradient.html but it's nothing more

I'm using python 2.7, my ggplot vesion is 0.6.8

Comment: Try upgrading to 0.9.3. I believe it'll be fixed there.